# Total price and price per unit microdata

Tags: schema, microdata

Currently trying to optimise our e-comm shop and google merchant products and I can't seem to get any further or get any other information on how to display a total price and a price per ct. 
Product.

I need to have the total price the customer pays displayed on the website (£100.00) the quantity they'll receive (100 ct), and the price per unit that they pay (£1.00).

But what would the pages microdata and JSON-LD be?

Thanks!

Comment: There is not enough information in this post for you to get a good answer. We need to see what you have tried, what has worked, what has not worked, and any errors you get. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Comment: Even if you failed, you can share what you already tried to put in your JSON-LD...

Answer (score 0):

One way to provide that sort of info is to start with the offer and use includesObject which has an amountOfThisGood.

offer
  price - 100
  includesObject
    amountOfThisGood - 100
    typeOfGood
      type - Product
      offer
        price - 1

However, I suspect systems including Google will not understand that yet.